# Rain Effect generation in a Unity VR project

Tags: unity, shaders, particles, virtual-reality, image-effects

I´m developing a VR project in Unity Engine and I need to implement a Rain Effect. I have considered the following:

- A VR game must run at least 90 frames per second.
- The Rain must be detailed.
- The Rain Drops interact with other objects.

These are the approaches I have considered:

- Particles Systems: I think it is expensive since there are two cameras rendering the scene and checking collision per particle could be expensive.
- Image Effect on the canvas: I think the result would be unreal, and there would not be interaction with other objects.

I have seen examples of rain effect like in Resident Evil 4, Halo Reach, Crysis, FarCry, Project Cars 2 VR and Batman Arkham Knight.

A last approach I haven´t considered yet is by shading, maybe shading would work for the rain drops in the cameras´ lens.

I would like to know optimal approaches to emulate rain effects without making too much computations.

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

## Particle collisions are super fast

That was one of the requirements Unity had when they added them in 4.0.0

> [From the blog](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2012/11/18/shuriken-world-particle-collision/)
>
> With Unity 4.0 we are adding support for world particle collsion detection. It’s quite awesome and very fast.
>
> We spent a lot of time optimizing world particle collisions and also did more than a few optimizations to Shuriken in general. Especially on mobile devices Shuriken got a very big performance boost.
>
> **Multithreading**
>
> Shuriken is multithreaded and so is collision detection.

So this should be fine, even for VR.